# How to disable service class log [log4j] message in Wavemaker

Tags: java, logging, log4j, wavemaker

I have loads of `log(INFO,"")` log messages in my all service classes, I need to disable those only `INFO` messages for now. For that, I edited my `/app/src/log4j.properties` file. and set as : 
`log4j.rootLogger=warn, stdout`
 So, It should display now only Warning and higher level logs, but when I execute code after made changes, it still shows `INFO` messages.

I think I need to set log level at package level, but *How can I set this package level in particular wavemaker?* [Here](http://dev.wavemaker.com/wiki/bin/wmdoc_6.6/ServerLogs) is some basic configuration info for `log4j` setup in `Wavemaker`, But it is not showing how to disable or which class need to set at level `warn` or something else to get rid of INFO messages.  I haven't added `log4j.proprties` file here, I will add if someone want to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Look for other uncommented lines in log4j.properties file that display INFO.  For example:

```
# logging for CloudFoundry upload
log4j.logger.com.wavemaker.tools.deployment.cloudfoundry=info

# logging for XHR Service
log4j.logger.com.wavemaker.runtime.service.WaveMakerService=info
```

Try commenting out these lines or change to warn.  Haven't tried this but it makes sense..

Comment: Tried both options; result none. Those log messages are configured inside `JavaServiceSuperClass`  class. so log4j.properties has no handle over it.